# Is there a way to track or record users entered taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

Is there a way to track, flag, or record a users entered taxonomy even if perhaps they may have changed it (tagging). So basically I am trying to set up a list of all the taxonomy tags a user created. The thing these tags can be changed and manipulated by the user so I am wondering if the originals can still be added to my list after they may have changed to a new tag. For example, a user recording places of employment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [Community Tags](http://drupal.org/project/community_tags) project.  We have used it on a few sites.  From the project page:

> The Module has three main features:
>   1. Stores who tagged what and when.
>   2. Allows for this information to be exposed with views.
>   3. Adds an easy AJAX interface for tagging nodes without going to node/edit.